# Measuring distance in arbitrary scale point cloud

Tags: computer-vision

I have one point cloud(point cloud of human feet) of arbitrary scale. If I have another point cloud(of human feet) with dimensions known, can I get the dimensions of a first point cloud? How will scaling work here?. Please feel free to give references as I am new to computer vision.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  How are the two clouds related?  If they're not related, then why would the second cloud help?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's like this, suppose I have your feet point cloud and we know your feet size. Once I take point cloud of my feet from a different camera and extrinsic, I want to get the measurements of my feet.  is it possible to measure the my feet point cloud dimensions using other techniques? As I don't have any reference point when I took point cloud of my feet.

Comment: If you know the scale for the second point cloud, it seems like you have everything you need; you can compute the size of your feet from it directly, ignoring the first point cloud.  If you don't have the scale for the second point cloud, then I don't see having two point clouds for the same object with no scale for either will help.  So the question doesn't make sense to me.  Probably I am misunderstanding something or missing some context.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. I have scale and dimensions of first point cloud but don't have scale and dimensions of the second point cloud. Using the first cloud as a template i want to know the measurements of second point cloud. I am thinking like shrinking the first point cloud with R-square error corresponding to second cloud. But i don't understand how to transform both clouds to same scale and coordinate system. Maybe i have to study more

Comment: OK.  This is starting to get clearer.  Are both point clouds of the same object?  Are they both taken from the same angle/position, or from different angles/positions?  Are you worried about noise?  What is the primary challenge to aligning the two?  Have you considered or tried any methods yet, and what have you seen as the problems or what do you anticipate as problems?  Please [edit] the question to state the problem clearly for someone who encounters this for the first time, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.